# Joints of a model are not visible in the joint panel

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've inserted two models into Gazebo using the GUI. One is the steering cart that is already included with Gazebo, the other is a Velodyne sensor which I created following the tutorials. The Velodyne model has a single revolute joint connecting the base to the top. When I load the Velodyne, I can apply a force to the join to get it to spin however, when I fix it to the cart and save it as a single model, I can no longer see the revolute joint for the Velodyne listed. I can however see the fixed joint I created and also all the joints for the carts wheels.

Is there a proper way to create a new model out of several pre-existing models?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16665/joints-of-a-model-are-not-visible-in-the-joint-panel./) by [ozan192](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3506/ozan192/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-07-10**:
Do you have an example model file to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Apparently, the best way to join to models to create a new one is to create a new model file and include the two previous models. See link below for details.

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=attach_gripper&cat=build_robot

---

Originally posted by [ozan192](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3506/ozan192/) with karma: 16 on 2017-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0